# Keep div in place, but relative

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you can see [here](http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/tracks.html): I want to create a page with the songs of a show, but when jQuery changes the height of one of the divs (on hover), the other div changes its position (it centers vertically). Normally, I would use

```
position:relative;
top:0px;
```

but in this case I want to put more divs under that (rows of five columns). Those have to go down a bit if one of the divs above expands.

Comment: you have malware on your site....its bringing up a google warning for me...

Comment: @KyleK that's what happens when you use free hosting.

Comment: Really? At all PCs in my house and those of my father it works properly. I use adBlock, but my father doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, add the following CSS:

```
.track{vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Thanx! ...also for the right editing ^^. I'll keep that in mind.